# Is this a example of zeugma or ellipsis?

Tags: relative-clauses, ellipsis, rhetoric

Do you think this sentence is a example of zeugma(syllepsis) or ellipsis?

> This decline in vigor with the passing of time is called ageing. **It is
>   one of the most unpleasant discoveries which we all make** **that** we must
>   decline in this way, **that** if we escape wars, accidents and disease we
>   shall eventually "die of old age", **and that** this happens at a rate
>   which differs little from person to person, so that there are heavy
>   odds in favour of our dying between the ages of sixty-five and eighty.

I think all the three *that*-clauses are all governed by 'it is one of the most unpleasant discoveries which we all make', i.e.

> It is one of the most unpleasant discoveries which we all make that we
>   must decline in this way.
>
> It is one of the most unpleasant discoveries which we all make that if
>   we escape wars, accidents and disease we shall eventually die of old
>   age.
>
> It is one of the most unpleasant discoveries which we all make that
>   this happens at a rate which differs little from person to person.

Am I right to understand this sentence in such a way?
Is it a example of zeugma (or syllepsis) or is it simply a kind of ellipsis?

Here is the full paragraph where this sentence is from:

> At the age of twelve years, the human body is at its most vigorous. It
>   has yet to reach its full size and strength, and its owner his or her
>   full intelligence; but at this age the likelihood of death is least.
>   Earlier, we were infants and young children, and consequently more
>   vulnerable; later, we shall undergo a progressive loss of our vigour
>   and resistance which, though imperceptible at first, will finally
>   become so steep that we can live no longer, however well we look after
>   ourselves, and however well society, and our doctors, look after us.
>   This decline in vigour with the passing of time is called ageing. **It
>   is one of the most unpleasant discoveries which we all make that we
>   must decline in this way, that if we escape wars, accidents and
>   disease we shall eventually 'die of old age', and that this happens at
>   a rate which differs little from person to person**, so that there are
>   heavy odds in favour of our dying between the ages of sixty-five and
>   eighty. Some of us will die sooner, a few will live longer -- on into
>   a ninth or tenth decade. But the chances are against it, and there is
>   a virtual limit on how long we can hope to remain alive, however lucky
>   and robust we are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The three "that" must be treated separately.

---

**The first** "that" has a partial meaning of "but", if "decline" implies "refusing":

> "... discoveries which we ... make ... **but** must decline."

It is not used to start explaining the content of a discovery.

If "decline" refers to losing vigor (as clarified after editing), then the first "that" (together with what follows) is also part of the enumeration (see below).

---

**The second and the third** "that" are just the introductions to descriptions of discoveries:

> - if we escape wars, accidents and disease, we shall eventually "die of old age"
> - this happens at a rate which differs little from person to person

The last 2 clauses are just an enumeration (of discoveries) - you can see it as an ellipsis, but not a regular one.

Comment: Thank you, virolono! And virolimo, I have added the original paragraph in my post. Can I understand that the first 'that' clause(we must decline this way) is also an enumeration of the most unpleasant discoveries: we must decline in a way of slowly losing vigor?

Comment: OK, I updated answer ;)